# VNC client not working -- Not able to see the changes happening on the other side

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

Here is the Problem: I have two computers connected in the same LAN.

I am trying to access one computer from another using Remote Desktop Viewer, I am able to see the remote desktop.

But when i click on any thing or perform any action, I dont see the result but the action is performed on the remote desktop..But it is not refreshed on the remote desktop screen..

For Ex:

1. Opened Remote Desktop viewer
2. Connected to the other computer which has yahoo home page opened
3. Clicked on the close button of the web page
4. Action is performed on the other computer (Yahoo page is closed).
5. On Remote Desktop screen i still see the Yahoo home page
6. Whatever action i perform on remote desktop screen i see the same screen(In this case yahoo home page)

Bottom line: Whatever screen i see on the start up of Remote Desktop viewer that is not getting refreshed.

So the thing is though i am able to perform actions on remote desktop, the screen is not refreshing..

How do i solve this?

I hope i made my point clear..

NOTE: I am connecting to Ubuntu 9.04 machine from Ubuntu 10.04LTS.. I am really not sure if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you have set up desktop effects on the pc/server that you're trying to connect to.  If this is the case, you can't use the built-in VNC server that comes with Ubuntu by default.  Instead, you have to use the x11vnc package (or something similar) that supports the "noxdamage" option.

See this question/answer for further details on how to set this up :
[VNC doesn't work with compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10232/currently-vnc-doesnt-work-with-compiz-will-you-fix-this-before-unity-is-releas)

Comment: Yes, I think it is the problem..Kudos for solving the issue..

Comment: Been there myself!  X11vnc is pretty easy to use.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge VNC expert, but I noticed when I set up VNC recently that it does not connect to my main desktop instance by default, but spawns a new instance.  You can make it do persistent desktops apparently - I haven't tried this yet:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Setting-Up-a-VNC-Server-with-Session-Resume-Support-52875.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If you are running wrong/old Nvidia Video Driver it can interfere with video server in vnc.
I uninstalled drivers, then went back and re-installed using sudo apt-get install nvidia-current. Works great and much faster refresh then without Nvidia driver, ie running generic driver.