# How to setup NX server and client?

Tags: remote-desktop, nx

I installed NX server on my desktop and able to run it successfully following this tutorial:

http://michigantelephone.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/how-to-install-nx-server-and-client-under-ubuntukubuntu-linux/

When i run the command `sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver –status` I am seeing the following output :

> NX> 900 Connecting to server .. NX>
>   110 NX Server is running.
>
> NX> 999 Bye.

It means i have setup NX server correctly..

But on other machine when i open NX client it is asking for hostname..what name should i give there?

Every tutorial is explaining about how to install and start NX server but not about how to connect to the server from client..

Could you guys please help me?

Thanks in Advance
Deter

Comment: I have decided to go for NX after vnc is not working..http://askubuntu.com/questions/20612/vnc-client-not-working-not-able-to-see-the-changes-happening-on-the-other-side

Comment: I think that should be `--status`, try with 2 hyphens.

Answer (score 3):

The NX session is defined by a session name (where you can enter whatever you want) and a host name, which is used to identify the server on the network.

Your host name can be a regular name (that will be resolved by your DNS or domain server, or /etc/hosts file, or whatever resolution system you may have.

If you don't have such a thing, you can simply put your server's IP address as the host name, and the client should connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to launch 'Angry IP Scanner' and scan for alive hosts in your LAN.
I have been using this little program for several years now on both windows and linux machines.

Download [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipscan/files/ipscan3-binary/)

Once you download it, open a terminal and do something like:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ dpkg -i ipscan_3.0-beta5_amd64.deb
```

Start it from the menu (Aplications -> Internet -> Angry IP Scanner) or from terminal with

```
ipscan &
```

Then scan your lan with these steps:

- Click the [IP] button (this puts this machine's IP in the scan target)
- Select the '\24' range in the Netmask pull-down menu (this puts a /24 range in the IP range to scan, ie 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255)
- click Start