# Share Screen with Multiple Viewers?

Tags: remote-desktop

I need a cross platform screen sharing solution for a presentation. Users might have Windows, Mac or Linux... I've successfully hosted before with Yugma, but after upgrading to 10.10 I can't get it to work on my main box. I would potentially use TeamViewer, but the "Presentation" mode doesn't work with Ubuntu as the host. Anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: How many clients are we talking about?  My answer here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/10232/currently-vnc-doesnt-work-with-compiz-will-you-fix-this-before-unity-is-releas/18176#18176) outlines how to use x11vnc, but I think you need TeamViewer type capabilities here (ie. 20+ clients connecting in via the internet)?

Comment: I only need 3 clients, and I've used VNC previously by poking a hole in my firewall, but performance is not great when there are multiple viewers...

Comment: this may suit better on [softwarerecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11098/3579)

Answer (score 3):

You can use VNC, for example [tightvnc](http://www.tightvnc.com/) offers exactly that, with view only (and remote access with separate password) mode.

Unfortunately, with tightvnc you can't share your current desktop. You can use x11vnc (sudo apt-get install x11vnc) to share your current desktop. For example tightvnc client is good for connecting from Mac OS X / Linux / Windows to any VNC server (including x11vnc and tightvnc).