# How do I set VNC Server so that on system reboot it is auto started?

Tags: vnc, xinetd

I was trying to make a VNC server in my Ubuntu 11.04, which can allow me to login even system reboots. Therefore, I have tried as following, but from vncviewer I can't connect.

## Server listening

1. Install

   ```
   $ sudo -s
   # apt-get install vnc4server xinetd
   ```
2. Security

   ```
   # vncpasswd /root/.vncpasswd
   Password:
   Verify:
   ```
3. As a service

   ```
   # vim /etc/xinetd.d/Xvnc
   service Xvnc
   {
       type = UNLISTED
       disable = no
       socket_type = stream
       protocol = tcp
       wait = yes
       user = root
       server = /usr/bin/Xvnc
       server_args = -inetd :1 -query localhost -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 -once -fp /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc -DisconnectClients=0 -NeverShared passwordFile=/root/.vncpasswd
       port = 5901
   }
   ```
4. Start the service

   ```
   # service xinetd stop
   # service xinetd start
   ```

## Client trying

```
$ vncviewer 192.168.1.125:1

TigerVNC Viewer for X version 1.0.90 - built May 10 2011 10:04:22
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
Copyright (C) 2000-2006 TightVNC Group
Copyright (C) 2004-2009 Peter Astrand for Cendio AB
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.

Wed Sep  7 10:08:20 2011
 CConn:       connected to host 192.168.1.125 port 5901
 main:        read: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try x11vnc - a very powerful, relatively easy to use solution.

Please [see my previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10232/currently-vnc-doesnt-work-with-compiz-will-you-fix-this-before-unity-is-releas/18176#18176) on a similar topic for more info.  That answer also points towards a number of different ways to set x11vnc up as a service on login.  I have this working for my own personal server and it's been completely reliable.

Comment: if i already have other VNC's, what should i do to remove them and freshly put x11vnc according to that other link.

Comment: Looking at your apt-get line above, I guess you'd just `apt-get remove vnc4server xinetd`, then `sudo apt-get install x11vnc`.  Certainly on my system here, xinetd is not installed, so it should be a simple reversal to undo what you've done and install x11vnc.  But if they're working, perhaps you could just leave them working - x11vnc is incredibly powerful/versatile/easy to setup, but at the end of the day, delivers the same basic functionality as vnc4server!

Answer (score 1):

I'm expecting that you already install vnc-server and xinetd
only you have you do the following

```
 iptables –I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT
 chkconfig vncserver on
 server vncserver restart
```

reboot then try on other PC if it's working.

```
reboot
```

if you want to access outside make sure you allow the traffic from port 5900 of your Router with the IP address of your VNC server.